# I want to add an animation when audio is loading due to lack of mobile data

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I want to add an animation when audio is loading due to lack of mobile data.
Currently i am working on a site in which i am facing delay of audio due to lacking of internet connection.

Comment: please add more details on what exactly are trying to achieve

Comment: https://arslan-chaudhry99.github.io/Killer-responsive-audio-site/

Checkout this link. When I click on the play button audio takes time to play.
I want to add an animation like loading animation when audio is loading